# In Blazor Server Side show where changes were made

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I have a list of sensors and as soon as new data arrives from a sensor I want the list entry to highlight/flash for one second or so. With that flash the user will be informed, that the sensor data has changed.

The sensor data arrives within an `event` and the UI refresh will be triggered by `StateHasChanged`.

Some thoughts: I had the idea to create a new class which has the senor data and a `HasChanged` property, but as I would like to use `MatBlazorTables` which uses `foreach` I am not able to change the `HasChanged` to false again after it renderes. The second thought I had was creating two lists, one with the "old" data and one with the new arrived data and then the razor-component looks where changes were made.

Are there simpler, cleaner solutions, maybe already embedded in Blazor I haven't discovered yet?

Comment: This sounds like a problem that [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) could help solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to use CSS animations - no C# or JS code required! (disclaimer: I'm not a CSS expert!)

Animations can be defined as a specific duration and repetition. When you add items to a Blazor list, Blazor adds them by diff'ing, so the existing items **are not changed** and so won't trigger the animation for new ones.

I've created a demo here: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/0qj50sch

**Example**

[image: Example of flash animation]

Comment: Fascinating, didn't knew that this was possible with pure CSS. The problem is, that I want to show the user when an item in the list was **changed** not that an item was added. Is that possible with CSS, too? I updated the blazorfiddle with the change button: blazorfiddle.com/s/hm4iw1up

Comment: @MaxR. sorry I didn't read the question very well! Yes, if you have an existing list of items, then you'd need to *add* the class to the item you want to flash. However, this will only update once of course. I did consider using a timer to remove the class but there was a simpler way - have two classes (with different names) and swap between them each time it updates. Sample:https://blazorfiddle.com/s/5m86vp64 - it's not perfect but it might be adaptable

Comment: Interesting, edge on chromium seems to omit the 2. class as it looks the same for the browser (which is actually true) so we have to change one little thing in one class to make it work. I set the 3. percantage from 90% to 89%. Also I set the class to the `td` instead of the `tr` element and set the flash background to `transparent`, so the background color stays the same. It all seems a little bit hacky and quirky but it works pretty well, eventhough I tried to find a solution (as mentioned above) without adding an extra property to my class. thx! https://blazorfiddle.com/s/440baf3h

Comment: @MaxR. yeah I had some issues when trying it out. It might be that Chrome does not like the class changing while the animation is still running..